# tikz: Error that appears only in a certain order of two pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, compilation-error, tikz-knots

I have a very strange behaviour in the following simple code. The purpose is to draw two knots by using tikz, with tikzlibrary knots.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{knots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1ex,y=1ex]
  \begin{knot}[consider self intersections=true, ignore endpoint intersections=false]
    \strand(0,0) to[out=right,in=up] (4,-4)
    to[out=down,in=up] (0,-8)
    to[out=down,in=down, looseness=3] (4,-8)
    to[out=up, in=down] (0,-4)
    to[out=up,in=left] (4,0)
    to[out=right, in=right, looseness=1.5] (2,-10)
    to[out=left,in=left, looseness=1.5] (0,0)
    ;
    \flipcrossings{1,2,4}
  \end{knot}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(25,0)}]
    \begin{knot}[consider self intersections=true, ignore endpoint intersections=false]
      \strand (0,0) to [out=0,in=90] (5,-8)
      to [out=-90,in=down, looseness=3](0,-8)
      to [out=up,in=180] (5,0)
      to [out=0, in=100] (9,-4)
      to [out=-80, in=-100, looseness=1.5] (-4,-4)
      to [out=80,in=180] (0,0)
      ;
      \flipcrossings{1,2,4}      
    \end{knot}
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The code as it is produce the error

```
ERROR: Missing number, treated as zero.

--- TeX said ---
<to be read again> 
                   {
l.28     \end{knot}
```

but if I cancel the firts knot, or if I switch the order of the two knots, the error disappear.

What it is happeninig???

Of course If the problem where in a single picture, ok I can accept to have the inverse order, the problem is that I arrived to this example-code after 1 hour trying to understand that error message in a more complicated file, where I cannot fix things just by switching pictures.

Comment: I've no error with your example. I'm using an up-to-date TeX Live 2023.

Comment: perfect!.... I also tryed overleaf, and gives me the same behaviour. So you  say that it is not a problem of code, rather of packages

Comment: If you get the error with exactly the shown code, I'd expect, that a complete update of the TeX distribution would help, because it does not happen with up-to-date TeX Live. If you are using overleaf, you would need to wait until release of TeX Live 2024 and installation of this at overleaf. Than you can switch from overleaf's (still available, but currently not up-to-date) TeX Live 2023 to TeX Live 2023. Maybe updating tikz and/or spath3 would also be enough.

Comment: Could you show the versions of the relevant packages?

Comment: If you put `\listfiles` before the `\documentclass`, then the log will list the packages and their versions at the end.

Comment: "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.6.6)  22 FEB 2024 10:37
"

Comment: LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1 L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>. Document Class: amsart 2020/05/29 v2.20.6
Package: amsmath 2021/10/15 v2.17l
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text
amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d 
Package: amsopn 2021/08/26 v2.02
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01
Package: pgfrcs 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a 
Package: pgf 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a 
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d 
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 
Package: graphics 2021/03/04 v1.4d
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 
Package: pgfsys 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a
pgfcore 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a

Comment: I don't know if I listed the relevand packages, I could attach the log file (if only I knew how to do :)